# Yield or return for Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I read several different examples/articles but I am still not sure about `yield` and `return`. I have two examples here from my code where I asked me that question. Which one to use?

**spider.py**

```
class LatindancecalendarSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "latindancecalendar"
    allowed_domains = ["latindancecalendar.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://latindancecalendar.com/festivals/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='eventline event_details']/a")
            ),
            callback="parse_event",
        ),
    )

    def parse_event(self, response):
        # event = ItemLoader(item=LatinDanceCalendarItem(), response=response)
        event = LatinDanceCalendarItemLoader(
            item=LatinDanceCalendarItem(), response=response
        )
        # event.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
        event.add_xpath("name", '//h1[@class="page-title"]/text()')
        event.add_xpath("date", '//div[@class="vevent"]/div/span/b/text()')
        return event.load_item()  # yield or return?
```

**items.py**

```
def lowercase_processor(self, values):
    for v in values:
        yield v.lower()  # yield or return?

class LatinDanceCalendarItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    city_in = lowercase_processor
```

Comment: Which use is more appropriate for your particular needs?

Comment: I read that `yield` creates a generator and doesn't "leave" the function. But that's where I struggle to understand if the `lowercase_processor` function should be left or not. There are many items that go through that function, but couldn't figure out if that's the relevant point.

Comment: Here the documentation uses `yield v.lower()`, but at the same time also `return parsed_length` or `return value` > https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

Comment: Using `return` in **items.py** will cause incomplete iterate over values. but in **spider.py** it is appropriate as long as it's end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yield will return a generator. The return will only return the first `v` in `values` and the rest of the loop is skipped. Basically if you use yield, you will get back a generator with all the values in lowercase. If you use a return it will just return the first value in lowercase.

Comment: Please check whether your answer provides a general explanation of a concept or really answers the question.

Comment: I removed the example code. Hopefully that answers the question.

Comment: So which one should be used? What is **the answer** to the question?

Comment: That actually helped me to understand it, thank you!

Comment: @FatihAkici It really depends on your use case. To put things simply, use the `yield`